# Django - How Updating Author Model in the mid-way?

Tags: django, django-models

I have `Author` model which looks like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I want to connect `Author` Model to `User` model and in the process add some additional fields in the `Author` model. Here is the updated version of `Author` model.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    ## additional fields
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bio = models.TextField()
```

`Author` model is also connected to the `Story` model via `ForeignKey`. My question is how do I update my Author model without deleting any Story related to it.

Comment: So far updating author model doesn't deleting entry in db.

Comment: just makemigrations and migrate your project, give it default values if needed.

Comment: What default value should I specify for User ?

Comment: You can get the first object in your User model :)

Comment: @Cody you can give null and blank True to user if you don't want to mess with migration time. Later you can assign user via Admin or shell...

Comment: @khuebui doing so results in IntegrityError

Comment: You can try as @RajaSimon suggest, delete the last migrations files if needed.

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are saying :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

And do makemigrations and migrate. Now you have the empty user field. Later you can add user in admin page or Can able to add user also in Shell.

Comment: but how do i remove `null=True` and `blank=True` from my models

Comment: Come again what mt models ?

Comment: I was saying "my models"

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your point. Can you bit clarify what you were saying

Comment: `null=True`, `blank=True` allows `user` field to have null value, is there any way to prevent it ?

Comment: So basically we are giving null value when migration. Because there is no other way to determine this `Author` belongs to `User`.  If you have large user base and large author's then this will be a problem. What I'm suggest is create a null value user first then assign the user in later stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145118/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-cody).